# How can I remove imagegick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, imagemagick

I failed to install `gem rmagick`, because ImageMagick was already installed in my OS X. How can I remove ImageMagick ? I can't find it as installed by MacPorts or Homebrew. I can't remember how I installed it. For info, when I run `convert --version`, I get:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-9 2012-05-12
```

When I run `sudo find . -name "ImageMagick*"` in `/`, I get

```
./usr/local/etc/ImageMagick
./usr/local/include/ImageMagick
./usr/local/include/ImageMagick/magick/ImageMagick.h
./usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.7.6
./usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.0
./opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/graphics/ImageMagick
```

and when I run `mdfind MagickWand.h`

```
/usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/api/MagickWand/struct__MagickWand.html
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/php/php5-magickwand/Portfile
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/php/php5-magickwand/files/patch-magickwand.h.diff
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/php/php5-imagick/files/patch-config.m4.diff
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/php/php-magickwand/Portfile
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/php/php-magickwand/files/patch-magickwand.h.diff
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/php/php-imagick/files/patch-config.m4.diff
```

Comment: it is obvious you installed it using `macports`. use it to uninstall

Comment: RMagick is a gem that requires ImageMagick for its functioning. Removing ImageMagick will render RMagick "useless".

Comment: @Anand installing the gem won't install `ImageMagick` ?

Comment: Nopes it doesn't. "RMagick is an interface between the Ruby programming language and the ImageMagick® and GraphicsMagick image processing libraries."